# How to extract the Data for give two columns condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
   dept_ID Year_join  salary  present
1     ID1     2000   10000   0 
2     ID1     2001   10000   0
3     ID1     2002   10000   0
4     ID1     2003   10000   0
5     ID1     2004   10000   1
6     ID2     2000   20000   0
7     ID2     2001   20000   1
8     ID2     2002   20000   0
9     ID3     2000   15000   1
10    ID1     2000   10000   0
11    ID1     2001   10000   0
12    ID1     2002   10000   0
13    ID1     2003   10000   0
14    ID1     2004   10000   0
15    ID2     2000   20000   1
16    ID2     2001   20000   0
17    ID2     2002   20000   0
18    ID3     2000   15000   0 
19    ID1     2000   10000   1
20    ID1     2001   10000   0
```

I want the extract the data of all department Id who are at least once is 1 and also if I want 500 unique dept_id data.
I have tried the below code but not getting the desired output.

```
dept_sub=df.dropna(subset=['dept_ID'])
df_1 = dept_sub[dept_sub['present'].isin(['1'])].copy()
s = df.groupby('dept_ID')['present'].nunique()
department = s.index[s.eq(1)].unique()
final_data = dept_sub[dept_sub['dept_ID'].isin(department)]
```

This is the desired output

```
  dept_ID Year_join  salary  present
1     ID1     2000   10000   0 
2     ID1     2001   10000   0
3     ID1     2002   10000   0
4     ID1     2003   10000   0
5     ID1     2004   10000   1
6     ID2     2000   20000   0
7     ID2     2001   20000   1
8     ID2     2002   20000   0
9     ID3     2000   15000   1
10    ID1     2000   10000   0
11    ID1     2001   10000   0
12    ID1     2002   10000   0
13    ID1     2003   10000   0
14    ID1     2004   10000   0
16    ID2     2001   20000   0
17    ID2     2002   20000   0
18    ID3     2000   15000   0 
20    ID1     2001   10000   0
```

This is the sample data of 20 rows. In actual my dataset shape is (500000,50) I want to extract the data of all 500 dept_id contains at least one present value==1 and rest present value==0 for that dept_ID

Comment: What is the desired output from the given input?

Comment: @ G. Anderson I have edit the question you can see the desired output

Answer (score 0):

If values in `present` are integers filter rows with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), get only first values by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and add all `False` for mask with same length like original, so possible filter out them by inverse mask `~`:

```
mask = (df[df['present'].eq(1)]
             .duplicated(subset=['dept_ID'])
             .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False))
```

If values in `present` are strings:

```
mask = (df[df['present'].eq('1')]
             .duplicated(subset=['dept_ID'])
             .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False))

df = df[~mask]
print (df)
   dept_ID  Year_join  salary  present
1      ID1       2000   10000        0
2      ID1       2001   10000        0
3      ID1       2002   10000        0
4      ID1       2003   10000        0
5      ID1       2004   10000        1
6      ID2       2000   20000        0
7      ID2       2001   20000        1
8      ID2       2002   20000        0
9      ID3       2000   15000        1
10     ID1       2000   10000        0
11     ID1       2001   10000        0
12     ID1       2002   10000        0
13     ID1       2003   10000        0
14     ID1       2004   10000        0
16     ID2       2001   20000        0
17     ID2       2002   20000        0
18     ID3       2000   15000        0
20     ID1       2001   10000        0
```

Comment: I am using this but its return me all data not specific I mentioned                                  
 data2 = pd.concat([data.chassis_id, data1], axis=1)


mask = (data2[data2['target'].eq('1')].duplicated(subset=['chassis_id']).reindex(data2.index, fill_value=False))

data2 = data2[~mask]
print(data2)

Comment: @jezael with real data.

Comment: @jezael how I can resolve this issue with real data? Can you help me.

Comment: @Anki - Hard question why not working with real data, can you change sample data for see what is problem?

Comment: @jezael I want to show you complete dataset but the column name is big and dataset shape is (300000,52). How to show you real dataset.

Comment: @jezael can I email you snapshot?

Comment: @jezel I didnt get your email id

Comment: I cant do anything there. I didn't get anything

Comment: @Anki - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=profile

Comment: can you give email id. I don't how to use StackOverflow completely sorry.

Comment: @jezael i got your profile but where I have to put the code

Comment: There is my email, send me your file to my email.

Comment: I found the whole page but didn't get email address.

Comment: @Anki - I write - run python code for email address. Do yo urun code from my profile?

Comment: @Anki- OK, if do it, got email ;)